# Keep Windows command window open

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I'm running a command through the Windows shell- an existing command window (cmd.exe). When I execute the command, the window closes, even though it's a freestanding window not tied to the command.

How can I keep the window open to see the output?

Comment: It's an executable invocation with some arguments. I copied and pasted the command. Even if the executable terminates, the console window should stay open.

Comment: I mean: how you invoke that executable? it shouldn't be attached (by default) to an existing console window

Comment: Through the command shell.

Comment: Unless the executable invokes a call to close the window it should stay open; could you please give an example of a command that has this behaviour?

Comment: It's an internal legacy tool; I simply invoked it with `tool.exe -args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply start a *child* `cmd` session because it'll share same window and if your custom tool actively closes its window (I wonder why) then it'll close your console and output will disappear.

There isn't much you can do if a program want to close console window but you can at least save its output to a file (to be inspected later with `type`). If you're working with that console and you don't want to close it then you can use `start cmd` to execute it in a new console window. Like this:

```
start cmd /c tool -args ^> output.txt
```

`tool` output will be available in `output.txt` after it finished.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the executable is closing the command window. Here is what you could try, may work. open a command shell. In the shell issue "cmd" and open another command shell. Run your executable in the newly opened command shell. You nested cmd will be exited, but you may still be able to see some of the output of your executable.